# Use character code of macro parameter

Tags: plain-tex, characters

How can the character code of a character received as a macro parameter be obtained?

As an example: In the MWE below, `\letterwithnum{<n>}` produces the n-th letter in the alphabet. `\getletternum{<letter>}` is supposed to do the opposide, but `` `\# `` is converted to 35 and the parameter replacement doesn't happen. How can I fix this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\letterwithnum#1{%
    \char\numexpr`\a-1+#1\relax%
}

\def\getletternum#1{%
    \the\numexpr`\#1-`\a+1\relax%
}

\begin{document}

\letterwithnum{11} % -> k

\getletternum{k} % -> 351-`1 with error

\end{document}
```

Comment: Now `‘#1` wasn't so hard @egreg, was it?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes That's not a backquote. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg True, but it's a lot less unsightly than `backquote #1`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes `\`#` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Very clever.  I tip my hat, but are you going to share the secret?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes `\`#no!\`#`  (I think we have an answer on meta somewhere)  (actually you can use `\\` ` to get a `\` ` in a code highlighted region)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Perhaps this: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208/formatting-sand-box (Werner's answer)

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes This is another (not exactly the same question though): https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7402/how-to-quote-a-left-quote-inline

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just using `` `#1 `` will work. Also the backslash in `\a` can be omitted. There are two ways for denoting an alphabetic constant:

```
`<char>
`\<char>
```

that is, the backquote *can* be followed by a macro with a one character name; such a macro is not interpreted as such, in this case, but is just a way to escape the character. It's only necessary for some special characters

```
\ # %
```

and some other that need the `^^` notation, such as

```
^^M ^^?
```

Thus, if you want to get the character code of `^^M`, you need

```
`\^^M
```

(it is 13, by the way). You can't input `` `% ``, so `` `\% `` is necessary and similarly for the backslash.

For letters the backslash is not needed, so you code can also be

```
\def\letterwithnum#1{%
    \char\numexpr`a-1+#1\relax
}

\def\getletternum#1{%
    \the\numexpr`#1-`a+1\relax
}
```

And `\newcommand` should be used with LaTeX.

I can also suggest using predefined functions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\letterfromnum}{m}
 {
  \int_to_alph:n { #1 }
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\getletternum}{m}
 {
  \int_from_alph:n { #1 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\letterfromnum{11} should print k

\getletternum{k} should print 11

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just use `#1`, instead of `\#1`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\letterwithnum#1{%
    \char\numexpr`\a-1+#1\relax%
}

\def\getletternum#1{%
    \the\numexpr`#1-`\a+1\relax%
}

\begin{document}

\letterwithnum{11} % -> k

\getletternum{k} % -> 351-`1 with error

\end{document}
```

[image]